# Parent-Child spark scala recursive udf with hive

Tags: scala, apache-spark, recursion, hive, user-defined-functions

I have an issue: I want to select a parent organization and all its childs and sub-childs: 
for example:
The parent organization ID is: 63261

I have the following organization table (org_id, parent_id):

```
   **org_id ||  parent_id**
    63549   ||  63261
```

If I check the children of 63549

```
**orga_id ||    parent_id**
1   58765 ||    63549
2   58766 ||    63549
3   58803 ||    63549
```

If I check the children of 58765, 58766, 58803, they don’t have.
So as a result, I want to retrieve the following IDs :

```
63261, 63549, 58765, 58766, 58803. All of them.
```

I tried a recursive query but Hive does not support recursive queries so I am thinking of developing a spark scala udf that takes the parent id and returns all its childs and sub childs until the last child that is not a parent.

Any ideas ?
thanks

Comment: can you please add some more sample data input & expected output ? with one you might get wrong result.

Comment: I think the example is clear, I need to start from the parent organization ID, find out it's child(s) and for each child I see if it has childs and so fourth

Comment: any ideas please ??

Comment: I don't understand your input & output .. please take few more samples for parent, child & add expected output, if possible

Answer (score 0):

I had developed these specific functions with scala and using spark:

```
package com.specific

import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}
import scala.collection.Map

/**
 * Utilities class for generic and specific functions
 */
object Utils {


  /**
   * gets the list of direct first level childs of a given organization
   * @param data
   * @param parent
   * @return list of child organizations ids
   */
  def getFirstLevelChildren(data: Map[Int, Int], parent: Int): List[Int] = {
    data.keySet.filter(key => parent == data.get(key).get).toList
  }

  /**
   * Recursive method to get all children and sub-children of a parent organization
   * @param data
   * @param parent
   * @return
   */
  def getChildren(data: Map[Int, Int], parent: Int): List[Int] = {
    var children = List.empty[Int]
    if (!getFirstLevelChildren(data, parent).isEmpty) {
      children = List.concat(children, getFirstLevelChildren(data, parent))
      for (child <- getFirstLevelChildren(data, parent)) {
        children = List.concat(children, getChildren(data, child))
      }
    }
    children
  }



  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val map2: Map[Int, Int] = Map(63549->63261,
                                  58765 -> 63549,
                                  58766 -> 63549,
                                  58803 -> 63549,
                                  10243 -> 6011,
                                  10257 -> 5996,
                                  10596 -> 6071,
                                  10652 -> 6076,
                                  10782->    6154,
                                  10873 -> 6134,
                                  1125  -> 197,
                                  11430 -> 6244,
                                  11692 -> 58803,
                                  1174  ->204,
                                  11951 ->6324,
                                  12369 ->6367,
                                  12544 ->6407,
                                  12759 ->5477,
                                  1280 -> 11692,
                                  1300 -> 11692,
                                  13183 ->  6950)
    val id = 63261
    List.concat((List(id)), getChildren(map2, id)).foreach(x => System.out.println(x))
  }
}
```

As a result I have the desired output: 
**63261
63549
58803
58766
58765
11692
1300
1280**

Anyone has better solutions ? I want to use this concept as a hive udf